# Choosing prior for exponential data

Tags: hypothesis-testing, bayesian

I'd like to calculate Bayes Factor for two exponential datasets, testing $H_0: \lambda_1 = \lambda_2$ against $H_1: \lambda_1\not=\lambda_2$, and here comes the prior probability $\pi$ for all $\lambda$'s.
**Question.** How I choose a prior $\pi$ for $\lambda$'s if I want it to be non-informative?

My exponential data models depressive symptoms total score so I guess that prior for $\lambda$'s should have some kind of connection to this, right? I was thinking about flat prior $\pi$  ~ $U[0,1]$.
I am aware of the existence of Jeffreys prior, but as I have learnt from [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/35789/bayes-factors-with-improper-priors) they're not to be applicable here, 'cause this prior is improper (or 'too improper' for computing Bayes Factors).

Comment: When I think of a non-informative prior, I often think of a uniform prior, so I think that should work

Comment: To my understanding, the [Bayes factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes_factor) doesn't require priors (it just comes from the ratio of two likelihoods). Are you after a ratio of posteriors (which would be a BF times a ratio of priors)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Gamma Prior that is almost flat (very little informative) with some specific hyper-parameters if you want a conjugate prior.

Another possbility is to use, for example, an $U[0,k]$ with very large $k$. In both cases how large or small the parameters must be to become very little informative depends on the scale of your data.